# How to transform multi-columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a excel file with multi-columns as below (Sorry but I don't know how to recreate it with pandas):
[image]

Below is my expected Output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': ['11000000000', '11200100000', '11710000000', '11000000000', '11200100000', '11710000000', '11000000000', '11200100000', '11710000000'], 
                   'Code Name': ['Car', 'Motorbike', 'Bike', 'Car', 'Motorbike', 'Bike', 'Car', 'Motorbike', 'Bike'],
                   'Date': ['19-02-2024', '19-02-2024', '19-02-2024', '19-02-2024', '19-02-2024', '19-02-2024', '19-02-2024', '19-02-2024', '19-02-2024'],
                   'Customer': ['Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer A', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer B', 'Customer ...', 'Customer ...', 'Customer ...'], 
                   'Point_1': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'Point_2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
df

    Code        Code Name   Date        Customer      Point_1   Point_2
0   11000000000 Car         19-02-2024  Customer A    NaN       NaN
1   11200100000 Motorbike   19-02-2024  Customer A    NaN       NaN
2   11710000000 Bike        19-02-2024  Customer A    NaN       NaN
3   11000000000 Car         19-02-2024  Customer B    NaN       NaN
4   11200100000 Motorbike   19-02-2024  Customer B    NaN       NaN
5   11710000000 Bike        19-02-2024  Customer B    NaN       NaN
6   11000000000 Car         19-02-2024  Customer ...  NaN       NaN
7   11200100000 Motorbike   19-02-2024  Customer ...  NaN       NaN
8   11710000000 Bike        19-02-2024  Customer ...  NaN       NaN
```

What should I do to get this result. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create DataFrame with `MultiIndex` first in index and columns by parameters `index_col` and `header` and then use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with first level and `dropna` parameter for avoid remove rows with missing values:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=[0,1,2], header=[0,1])

#test MultiIndex in columns
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('Customer A', 'Point_1'),
            ('Customer A', 'Point_2'),
            ('Customer B', 'Point_1'),
            ('Customer B', 'Point_2'),
            ('Customer ...', 'Point_1'),
            ('Customer ...', 'Point_2')],
           names=['Customer', None])

#test MultiIndex in index
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('11000000000',       'Car', '19-02-2024'),
            ('11200100000', 'Motorbike', '19-02-2024'),
            ('11710000000',      'Bike', '19-02-2024')],
           names=['Code', 'Code Name', 'Date'])
```

EDIT: There is problem with missing values in headers, so is possible use alternative solution - create MultiIndex first in columns and use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xls', header=[0,1])

df = df.set_index(df.columns[:3].tolist()).rename_axis(df.columns[:3].get_level_values(0))
print (df)
                                 Customer A         Customer B          \
                                    Point_1 Point_2    Point_1 Point_2   
Code        Code Name Date                                               
11000000000 Car       19-02-2024        NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN   
11200100000 Motorbike 19-02-2024        NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN   
11710000000 Bike      19-02-2024        NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN   

                                 Customer …          
                                    Point_1 Point_2  
Code        Code Name Date                           
11000000000 Car       19-02-2024        NaN     NaN  
11200100000 Motorbike 19-02-2024        NaN     NaN  
11710000000 Bike      19-02-2024        NaN     NaN
```

---

```
out = df.stack(0, dropna=False).reset_index()
print (out)
          Code  Code Name        Date      Customer  Point_1  Point_2
0  11000000000        Car  19-02-2024  Customer ...      NaN      NaN
1  11000000000        Car  19-02-2024    Customer A      NaN      NaN
2  11000000000        Car  19-02-2024    Customer B      NaN      NaN
3  11200100000  Motorbike  19-02-2024  Customer ...      NaN      NaN
4  11200100000  Motorbike  19-02-2024    Customer A      NaN      NaN
5  11200100000  Motorbike  19-02-2024    Customer B      NaN      NaN
6  11710000000       Bike  19-02-2024  Customer ...      NaN      NaN
7  11710000000       Bike  19-02-2024    Customer A      NaN      NaN
8  11710000000       Bike  19-02-2024    Customer B      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Sorry but it not worked as expect. Please check screenshot in my updated question.

Comment: @hoatran - Is possible share sample excel file? Hard test without file.

Comment: Sure, you can check it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16zL43tOKpz8srQo0WOG99umwqKDr6Kbv/edit#gid=863247321

Comment: @hoatran - request sent

Comment: @hoatran - Can you check EDIT in answer?